# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n809nd4Zu4).

I'm getting the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener')`

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My YT Bookmarks",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Saving timestamps in YT videos",
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "assets/bookmark.png",
        "assets/play.png",
        "assets/delete.png",
        "assets/save.png"
      ],
      "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/ext-icon.png",
      "24": "assets/ext-icon.png",
      "32": "assets/ext-icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "My YT Bookmarks",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
  if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("youtube.com/watch")) {
    const queryParameters = tab.url.split("?")[1];
    const urlParameters = new URLSearchParams(queryParameters);
    console.log(urlParameters);

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
      type: "NEW",
      videoId: urlParameters.get("v"),
    });
  }
});
```

does `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` exist? It's mentioned on [this documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#filters) but when I click the link for tabs.onUpdated [I get 404'd](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

When I try the filter method mentioned in the docs I get service worker registration error status code 15.

Comment: You probably look at an old error from your previous incorrect attempts. Click the `clear all` button and reload the extension.